# Using unsafePerformIO in a guard condition

Tags: arrays, haskell, io, monads, io-monad

I have a function like this:

```
jac :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> IOArray (Int,Int) Double -> IO Double
jac m k mu nu arr
  | nu!!0 == 0 = return 1
  | length nu > m && nu!!m > 0 = return 0
  | m == 1 = return $ x!!0^(nu!!0) * theproduct (nu!!0)
  | k == 0 && CONDITION = XXX
  | otherwise = YYY
```

The `CONDITION` must check that that element `(1,1)` of the array `arr` is different from 0. But to get this element, one must do

```
element <- readArray arr (1,1)
```

I don't see how to do. Except with `unsafePerformIO`. Is it safe to use it here ? I mean:

```
  | k == 0 && unsafePerformIO (readArray arr (1,1)) /= 0 = XXX
```

Otherwise, how could I do ?

Comment: Write a new function that doesn't work with `IO`s, then write this function in terms of that function, using `do`-notation. Don't use `unsafePerformIO` unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: "Otherwise, how could I do ?" -- with `do`! :) with `unsafePerformIO` the return type of hour function wouldn't have been `IO Double`, but just `Double`. But since you return the `IO Double` value, you must create that value, and that is done easiest with the `do` notation. (as you have discovered, and show in your answer) :)

Comment: Your condition doesn't have to be in a guard for the `jac` function. You can just as easily write: `| otherwise = do {value <- readArray arr (1,1); if value /= 0 then .......`

Comment: Does your `jac` function actually mutates the array? If not, why not just freeze it and use pure indexing in the guard and in the body of the function

Answer (score 5):

Let's make a simplified version of your question.

Let's say we want to make the following function. It tells us whether or not both of the `Int` values are equal to `0`. Problem is, it contains an `IO`. Your current method is this:

```
-- THIS IS BAD CODE! This could easily cause unexpected behaviour.
areBothZero :: Int -> IO Int -> IO Bool
areBothZero a b
    | a == 0 && unsafePerformIO b == 0 = return True
    | otherwise                        = return False
```

This shows a misunderstanding of monads. In Haskell, `unsafePerformIO` as a general rule shouldn't be used, unless you want to achieve a certain effect that pure computation cannot achieve. However, this kind of situation is perfectly achievable using the monad operations, which are, unlike `unsafePerformIO`, perfectly safe.

This is how we achieve this. Firsly, write the logic outside the context of `IO`:

```
areBothZeroLogic :: Int -> Int -> Bool
areBothZeroLogic a b
  | a == 0 && b == 0 = True
  | otherwise        = False
```

Then, we pipe that up to the `IO` logic we want:

```
areBothZeroIO :: Int -> IO Int -> IO Bool
areBothZeroIO a mb = do
    b <- mb -- Use do-notation to work with the value 'inside' the IO:
    return $ areBothZeroLogic a b
```

Immediately, this **separates `IO` logic from pure logic**. This is a fundamental design principle in Haskell that you should always try to follow.

---

Now, onto your problem.

Your problem is much more messy and has several other issues, which suggests to me that you haven't considered how best to split the problem up into smaller peices. However, a better solution may look something like this, maybe with better names:

```
--                              Look here! vvvvvv    vvvvvv
jacPure :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Double -> Double
jacPure m k mu nu arrVal
  | nu!!0 == 0                 = 1
  | length nu > m && nu!!m > 0 = 0
  | m == 1                     = x!!0^(nu!!0) * theproduct (nu!!0)
  | k == 0 && arrVal /= 0      = XXX
  | otherwise                  = YYY

jac :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> IOArray (Int,Int) Double -> IO Double
jac m k mu nu arr = do
    arrVal <- readArray arr (1,1) -- Use do-notation to work with the value 'inside' the IO:
    return $ jacPure m k mu nu arrVal
```

You should see immediately why this is much better. When implementing logic, who cares what's going on in the `IO` domain? Including an `IO` in what should be pure logic is like telling an author about the acidity of the paper their book will be printed on—it isn't relevant to what their job is. Always separate logic and `IO`!

There are of course other ways of doing this, and some could very well be better than the way I have suggested. However, it is not possible to know with the code you have provided which the best path would be. You should aim to learn more about monads and get better at using them, so you can make this judgement on your own.

---

I suspect this question is borne from a lack of understanding of Monads and monadic operations. If you are a beginner, I recommend reading [the relevant LYAH chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads), which I found helpful as a beginner too.

Comment: That cannot work like this, because `YYY` involves `arr`, not only `arrVal`. I've found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to combine the last two cases:

```
jac m k mu nu arr
  ...
  | k == 0 = do
       element <- readArray arr (1,1)
       case element of
         0 -> YYY
         _ -> XXX
  | otherwise -> YYY
```

Comment: This is not correct. My `otherwise` condition must trigger `YYY` when `k /= 0`

Comment: Fixed by adding a final case. This duplicates `YYY`, but that can be factored out of this function if it's nontrivial.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have

```
areBothZero :: Int -> IOArray Int Int -> IO Bool
areBothZero a b
  | a == 0 && unsafePerformIO (readArray b 0) == 0 = return True
  | otherwise = return False
```

I think it's worth thinking about what can go wrong. Suppose I write

```
do
  x <- areBothZero a b
  -- Change the value in b[0]
  y <- areBothZero a b
```

Now there are two identical function calls, so the compiler is perfectly free to rewrite this:

```
do
  let m = areBothZero a b
  x <- m
  -- change b
  y <- m
```

The first time we run `m`, we perform the `IO`, reading `b` and getting an action `return True` or `return False`. We run that action and bind the result to `x`. The next time, we already have an action, so we run it, producing the same result. Any change to `b` is ignored.

This is only *one* of the ways things can go wrong with `unsafePerformIO`, so watch out!

---

I think there are one and a half ways it's reasonable to use `unsafePerformIO` or (in some cases) `unsafeDupablePerformIO` routinely. The entirely reasonable one is to wrap an "essentially pure" FFI call that just performs a mathematical calculation in another language. The less reasonable one is to create a global `IORef` or (more often) `MVar`. I think this is less reasonable because global variables have a certain tendency to turn out not to be as global as you thought once a year or two has passed. Most other uses of these unsafe `IO` operations require very careful thought to get right These tend to be in libraries like `monad-par` and `reflex` that introduce whole new styles of computation to Haskell. They also tend to be subtly buggy, sometimes for years, until someone figures out just what needs to happen to make them right. (Not to toot my own horn too much, but I think I'm probably one of the top handful of people in the world at reasoning about unsafe `IO`, and I very much prefer to avoid it when possible. This stuff has tripped up some of the best Haskell programmers and most important GHC developers.)

Comment: FFI calls can be declared as pure, by the way. `unsafePerformIO` is not required.

Comment: @immibis that's not always true: `bracket malloc free some_ffi_call` gives you an `IO` value but not necessarily an impure function.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution. I pass the value of the array element in addition.

```
jac :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> IOArray (Int,Int) Double -> Double -> IO Double
jac m k mu nu arr elt
  | nu!!0 == 0 || m == 0 = return 1
  | length nu > m && nu!!m > 0 = return 0
  | m == 1 = return $ x!!0^(nu!!0) * theproduct (nu!!0)
  | k == 0 && elt /= 0 = XXX
  | otherwise = do
    e <- readArray arr (1, 1)
    jck <- jac (m-1) 0 nu nu arr e
    ......
```

Maybe my question was not precise enough...

Answer (score 1):

Not terribly elegant, but should do:

```
jac :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> IOArray (Int,Int) Double -> IO Double
jac m k mu nu arr
  | nu!!0 == 0 = return 1
  | length nu > m && nu!!m > 0 = return 0
  | m == 1 = return $ x!!0^(nu!!0) * theproduct (nu!!0)
  | otherwise = do
     v <- readArray arr (1,1)
     case () of
        _ | k == 0 && v /= 0 -> XXX
          | otherwise        -> YYY
```

Alternatively, read from the array at the very beginning:

```
jac :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> IOArray (Int,Int) Double -> IO Double
jac m k mu nu arr = do
   v <- readArray arr (1,1)
   case () of
      _ | nu!!0 == 0 = return 1
        | length nu > m && nu!!m > 0 = return 0
        | m == 1 = return $ x!!0^(nu!!0) * theproduct (nu!!0)
        | k == 0 && v /= 0 -> XXX
        | otherwise        -> YYY
```